# Automatically add newline at end of curl response body

Tags: curl

If the HTTP response body for a curl request doesn't contain a trailing newline, I end up with this really annoying condition where the shell prompt is in the middle of the line, and escaping is messed up enough that when I put the last curl command on the screen, deleting characters from that curl command deletes the wrong characters.

For example:

```
[root@localhost ~]# curl jsonip.com
{"ip":"10.10.10.10","about":"/about"}[root@localhost ~]#
```

Is there a trick I can use to automatically add a newline at the end of a curl response, to get the prompt back on the left edge of the screen?

Comment: None of these answers work for me with whatever version of curl my cygwin install has; only wrapping the entire curl command in an echo statement does, e.g. `echo "$(curl localhost:8001/api)"`, re this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217611/110338

Comment: for json specifically, ```curl -s https://jsonip.com | jq```

Answer (score 621, accepted):

From the man file:

> To better allow script programmers to get to know about the progress of
>   curl, the -w/--write-out option was introduced. Using this, you can specify
>   what information from the previous transfer you want to extract.
>
> To display the amount of bytes downloaded together with some text and an
>   ending newline:
>
> ```
> curl -w 'We downloaded %{size_download} bytes\n' www.download.com
> ```

So try adding the following to your `~/.curlrc` file:

```
-w "\n"
```

Comment: You can run the following command that does that for you: `echo '-w "\n"' >> ~/.curlrc`

Comment: I always add `-w "\n"` manually to every curl command and TIL `~/.curlrc` exists!

Comment: this may not work under git-bash on Windows; I added `-w "\nKLJLJKLJ LJKLLKJ"` to my `~/.curlrc` and ran a curl and got neither a new line or the weird characters.

Comment: @jcollum Some Windows ports prefer `_` over `.`. Chances are your curl is looking for `~/_curlrc` and consequently `echo '-w "\n"' >> ~/_curlrc` will probably work. It does for me. btw: curl will complain over unescaped whitespace

Comment: There's value in using the command line with `-w "\n"` or appending `; echo` over modifying your `.curlrc`. If you modify your curlrc, some scripts may break if they do not handle a newline at the end of the response data. I personally would stick with the additions on the command line over modifying the rc.

Comment: I would use a shell alias rather then modifying the `~/.curlrc` to prevent scripts to break

Comment: Doing this will break hash checks on files downloaded with curl since it adds the extra newline, use at your own risk!

Comment: Not working well while `pip_configs | curl --config - --parallel --parallel-immediate --parallel-max 10` as I found some respnses are merged like `{a:1}{a:1}{a:1}{a:1}\n\n\n\n`.Is there a fix for that?

Answer (score 148):

Use this:

```
curl jsonip.com; echo
```

If you need *grouping* to feed a *pipe* :

```
{ curl jsonip.com; echo; } | tee new_file_with_newline
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{"ip":"x.x.x.x","about":"/about"}
```

This is *that* simple ;)

(and not limited to curl command but all commands that not finish with a newline)

Comment: Is there any way to wrap this in a script or bash alias or anything similar? Typing "; echo" at the end of every line can get tedious, and I feel like this should be able to be automated somehow.

Comment: On SO, it's better to provide some search effort. Finding how to put this in an alias or script is obvious.

Comment: Notice that adding the echo command clears the exit code from curl command.  The -w "\n" option to curl suggested in the most popular answer keeps the curl exit code available for inspection.

Comment: How to get `-w "\n"` works when piping to curl like `pip_as_config | curl --config - --parallel --parallel-immediate --parallel-max 10` as some respnses are merged like `{a:1}{a:1}{a:1}{a:1}\n\n\n\n` due to parallelized requests?

Answer (score 22):

For more info as well as a clean new line after curl

**`~/.curlrc`**

```
-w "\nstatus=%{http_code} %{redirect_url} size=%{size_download} time=%{time_total} content-type=\"%{content_type}\"\n"
```

(More options are available [here](https://helpmanual.io/man1/curl/))

`redirect_url` will be blank if the request doesn't get redirected or you use `-L` to follow the redirect.

Example output:

```
~ ➤  curl https://www.google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=FW">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>

status=302 https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=FW size=262 time=0.044209 content-type="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
~ ➤
```

**Edit**, to make things more readable you can add ANSI colours to the `-w` line, it's not that easy to write directly, but [this](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/init-desktop) script can generate a `~/.curlrc` file with colours.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pathlib import Path
import click
chunks = [
    ('status=', 'blue'),
    ('%{http_code} ', 'green'),
    ('%{redirect_url} ', 'green'),
    ('size=', 'blue'),
    ('%{size_download} ', 'green'),
    ('time=', 'blue'),
    ('%{time_total} ', 'green'),
    ('content-type=', 'blue'),
    ('\\"%{content_type}\\"', 'green'),
]
content = '-w "\\n'
for chunk, colour in chunks:
    content += click.style(chunk, fg=colour)
content += '\\n"\n'

path = (Path.home() / '.curlrc').resolve()
print('writing:\n{}to: {}'.format(content, path))
path.write_text(content)
```

Answer (score 5):

The general solution for bash is to add a newline symbol into the command prompt:

See related question ([How to have a newline before bash prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114694/how-to-have-a-newline-before-bash-prompt)
 ) and corresponding [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114696)

This solution covers each command, not only curl.

```
echo $PS1 # To get your current PS1 env variable's value aka '_current_PS1_'
PS1='\n_current_PS1_'
```

The only side-effect is that you get command prompt after each 2nd line.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get a new line added dynamically to prompt when command output didn't have a new line at end. So it works not only with `curl` but also any other command.

```sh
# https://github.com/dylanaraps/pure-bash-bible#get-the-current-cursor-position
new_line_ps1() {
  local _ y x _
  local LIGHT_YELLOW="\001\033[1;93m\002"
  local     RESET="\001\e[0m\002"

  IFS='[;' read -p $'\e[6n' -d R -rs _ y x _
  if [[ "$x" != 1 ]]; then
    printf "\n${LIGHT_YELLOW}^^ no newline at end of output ^^\n${RESET}"
  fi
}

PS1="\$(new_line_ps1)$PS1"
```

my answer in UL site: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/647881/14907

Comment: This is the real answer!