# Why does a rails render plain: output a percentage sign on the command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, curl

I have an api as part of my rails app, when a call comes in the controller responds with;

```
render plain: "OK - Request accepted",status: :ok, content_type: "text/html"
```

the output in terminal is

```
OK - Request accepted%
```

[image]

what does the percentage sign mean and where does it come from?
can I remove it?
( I'm accessing the url via curl and using iterm )

Comment: What is your shell command prompt?

Comment: I  found something similar in the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658510/curl-json-post-request-via-terminal-to-a-rails-app
I am not sure if that can help understanding your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your shell prompt.

Configure `curl` to add a newline to the output -- cf [Automatically add newline at end of curl response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849584/automatically-add-newline-at-end-of-curl-command)

Look example:

```
bash: PS1=foo
foo: curl -H -i  'http://localhost:3000/'
OK - Request acceptedfoo:
```

add with `\n`:

```
foo: curl -H -i  'http://localhost:3000/' -w '\n'
OK - Request accepted
foo:
```