# the result of curl command from mac bash is mixed with next command line

Tags: bash, curl

[image: wrong model show]

[image: right model show]

when typing 'curl' in mac bash,the result is mixed with the next command line. the model which i want is like the second pic.

Comment: Then add a newline to what you return.

Comment: can you rephrase? I don't understand the question

Answer (score 0):

Your document you got from the web does not end cleanly with a newline, so when the program 'curl' exits, your shell wakes up and prints starting where the cursor is, which means it looks like you have a mixed-up output. You don't.

You can do two things on that "curl" line to get the next shell prompt off on its own.

```sh
curl http://localhost/hello; echo
```

Comment: thx ,it is a way to solve this problem, but everytime typing echo command make me feel not good, i find  adding  -w "\n" in ./curlrc file is a better way.

Comment: this is link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849584/automatically-add-newline-at-end-of-curl-response-body