# json2csv output multiple jsons to one csv

Tags: json, bash, csv, json2csv

I am using json2csv to convert multiple json files structured like

```
{
  "address": "0xe9f6191596bca549e20431978ee09d3f8db959a9",
  "copyright": "None",
  "created_at": "None"
  ...
}
```

The problem is that I need to put multiple json files into one csv file.

In my code I iterate through a hash file, call a curl with that hash and output the data to a json. Then I use `json2csv` to convert each json to csv.

```bash
mkdir -p curl_outs
{ cat hashes.hash; echo; } | while read h; do 
    echo "Downloading $h"
    curl -L https://main.net955305.contentfabric.io/s/main/q/$h/meta/public/nft > curl_outs/$h.json; 
    node index.js $h; 
    json2csv -i curl_outs/$h.json -o main.csv;
done
```

I use `-o` to output the json into csv, however it just overwrites the previous json data. So I end up with only one row.

I have used `>>`, and this does append to the csv file.

```
json2csv -i "curl_outs/${h}.json" >> main.csv
```

But for some reason it appends the data's keys to the end of the csv file
[image]
I've also tried

```
cat csv_outs/*.csv > main.csv
```

However I get the same output.

How do I append multiple json files to one main csv file?

Comment: You might try changing your curl command to add a following `echo` to add a newline to the curl output.  Something like:  `curl -L https://your.url.here; echo;  | tee curl_outs/$h.json;`.  You may have some luck investigating the `-w` for curl per the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849584/automatically-add-newline-at-end-of-curl-response-body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from the image and your description what's wrong with `>>`, but it looks like maybe the CSV file doesn't have a trailing line break, so appending the next file (`>>`) starts writing directly at the end of the last row and column (cell) of the previous file's data.

I deal with CSVs almost daily and love the GoCSV tool. Its [stack subcommand](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#stack) will do just what the name implies: stack multiple CSVs, one on top of the other.

In your case, you could download each JSON and convert it to an individual (*intermediate*) CSV. Then, at the end, stack all the intermediate CSVs, then delete all the intermediate CSVs.

```bash
mkdir -p curl_outs
{ cat hashes.hash; echo; } | while read h; do 
    echo "Downloading $h"
    curl -L https://main.net955305.contentfabric.io/s/main/q/$h/meta/public/nft > curl_outs/$h.json; 
    node index.js $h; 
    json2csv -i curl_outs/$h.json -o curl_outs/$h.csv;
done

gocsv stack curl_outs/*.csv > main.csv;

# I suggested deleting the intermediate CSVs
# rm curl_outs/*.csv
# ...
```

I changed the last line of your loop to `json2csv -i curl_outs/$h.json -o curl_outs/$h.csv;` to create those *intermediate* CSVs I mentioned before.  Now, gocsv's stack subcommand can take a list of those intermediate CSVs and give you main.csv.

Comment: Hi, I like the idea of this. Can you please explain what individual (intermediate) means?

Comment: Also, im quite new to bash. How would I stack a directory of csv's?